# How to iterate and show the transaction input data?

Tags: node.js, transactions, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to view the input values given to a transaction with transaction **`Id`**, I could get response like Resource

```
{id =org.com.TestNetwork.CreatePPR#2sdf34r23dwed235asdasr345wrwes908}
```

where **`CreatePPR`** is my transaction name,

I need to get the input values given to this transaction.
How could I get the values with this **`Id`**?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way to start looking at this is to use the composer-rest-server and use a GET request against your CreatePPR transaction.  You can use the GET to retrieve all those transactions or the GET with a specific Transaction ID to retrieve a single transaction.

You can also write queries that will generate endpoints in the REST server and there is a [tutorial on Queries](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/queries) in the composer documentation.

If you are trying to retrieve the Transaction using the Javascript API your code may look something like this:

```
async function tGetTranCreatePPR ()
{

const BusinessNetworkConnection = require('composer-client').BusinessNetworkConnection;

var bnc = new BusinessNetworkConnection;
await bnc.connect('admin@PPR-network');

const factory = bnc.getBusinessNetwork().getFactory();
const myPPRRegistry = await bnc.getTransactionRegistry('org.com.TestNetwork.CreatePPR');
var myPPR = await myPPRRegistry.get('2sdf34r23dwed235asdasr345wrwes908');
console.log('myPPR: ',myPPR);
return;
}
```

That console.log will print the whole object, but you can refine that to specify the parameters of the transaction.  This example does a `get` but there is also `getAll` which returns an array, and there is also `resolve` (and `resolveAll`) which will resolve any relationships you have used as parameters to the Transaction.  The Composer Javascript [API reference is here.](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/api/client-transactionregistry)